# Constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: real-numbers, integers

I have been told that the real number line $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed from the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$.

How exactly is that true? Surely, the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$ would give a set of ordered pairs of numbers? How is this equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Integer part and fractional part. The integer is whatever's to the left of the decimal point; and the fractional part is everything to the right.

Comment: I'd say it is the opposite : $[0,1)$ is constructed by quotienting $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Why do you think "constructed from" means "equivalent" and why do you think "equivalent" means "is the exact same thing" and why do you think "constructed from" means "leave alone exactly as is"?  (a,b) in Z x [0,1) is an ordered pair.  But f(a,b) = a + b is a real number.  For any real number r and can find an integer n so that n <= r < n+1 so (n, r-n) in Z x[0,1), and f(n,r-n) = r.  So clearly R can be constructed from Z x [0,1) by "putting them all through" f.

Comment: @user1952009 it depends on what "constructed" means.  To create f(a,b) = a + b one has to assume R already exists so in that sense you are right; finding a function that maps Zx[0,1) isn't "contruction"-- defining and proving the existence of a number system.  On the other hand if "contruction" simply means finding a way to "convert" Zx[0,1) to R than f(a,b) = a + b certainly does that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection $f((x,r)) = x + r$, so $x$ is the integer part of the real number (before the digital point) and $r$ is the part after the digital point. Of course this assumes we write $1$ as corresponding to $(1,0)$ etc.

This is a bijection but not a homeomorphism (as the product is disconnected as a topological space).

Answer (score 2):

If you had $\mathbb{R}$, a natural map from the set you have to $\mathbb{R}$ would be
$$\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$(x,y) \mapsto x+y.$$
This is a bijection, as you can verify. However, since we "do not have" $\mathbb{R}$, we must "define":

$$\mathbb{R}:=\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1).$$

But... I think that by any reasonable meaning of "construct", you are entailing at least the operations and ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. And I see no easy way to do this in the set above without using explicitly (or at least "implicitly explicitly") the operations and ordering in $\mathbb{R}$, which would turn out to be circular.

---

If you admit as given the "structure" inherited by $[0,1)$ (although this is unclear, since it is not a good algebraic structure. It is an ordered set in a natural way, but the operations are not defined on all elements), we can proceed as follows to get the operations:

We use the lexicographic order on "$\mathbb{R}$". From the order, we already have the topology.

To do addition, if $x+y$ is defined, then
$$(n,x)+(m,y):=(n+m,x+y).$$
Now, before defining addition in the whole set, we define what it means to multiply by two in $[0,1)$, a unary operation which we will call $d$.

If $x<1/2$, we define $d(x)=2x$. If $x \geq 1/2$, we define $d(x)=x-(1-x)$*. Now we can define addition everywhere as follows:
if $x+y$ is not defined, then
$$(n,x)+(m,y):=\left(n+m+1,d\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)\right).$$

Having defined addition, we have a natural way to define multiplication by integers (we can verify that, indeed, our set with addition is an Abelian group).
Now, to define multiplication, we do
$$(n,x)\cdot(m,y):=(nm,0)+n(0,y)+m(0,x)+(0,xy).$$

---

*- $(1-x)$ can be defined as $\sup\{y \in [0,1) \mid x+y \text{ is defined}\}$ (with regards to what "is defined" means if it is not clear, see Ian's comment below). For $x \neq 0$ this is well-defined. Hence, it is well-defined for all $x \geq 1/2$, as is needed for our definition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For the ordering it is easy, once you have the ordering on $[0,1)$, to compare $(a,b)$ with $(c,d)$, first compare $b$ and $d$. If they're the same, compare $a$ with $c$. For the operations, you can make sense of "let $a$ be the bigger of $a$ and $c$, if $a>1-c$ then...else..." That gets you addition and subtraction. Can we do something similar to get multiplication?

Comment: @Ian You're right, but I (maybe mistakenly) thought about purging away any structure on $[0,1)$, including its ordering, since constructing such a structure would be something similar to using an already constructed $\mathbb{R}$ (that's what I meant by "implictily explicitly"), but this was silly I think. I will add information to the answer.

Comment: @Ian I've updated the answer. Please tell me if there is any issue : ).

Comment: It's a bit messy because you haven't characterized when $x+y$ fails to be defined. Yet there is basically a simple answer: $\max \{ x,y \} \geq 1-\min \{ x,y \}$. (Issues: 1. we don't have $1$, so we need to get $1-x$ from somewhere. 2. 1-0 isn't in $[0,1)$. But then, we could handle that case separately.) Otherwise it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$
f:\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)\to\mathbb R
$$
as follows: for any $(m,x)\in \mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$, $ f(m,x)=m+x$. Then $f$ is a bijective map. I don't know if that is what you mean with 'contructed'

Answer (score 0):

> I have been told that the real number line $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed from the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$.

"constructed from" is perhaps relatively vaguely defined, but I assume you mean "has the same cardinality as" or, equivalently, "a bijection exists to".

$$ f((n, r)) = n + r $$ is exactly such a bijection.

> How exactly is that true? Surely, the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1)$ would give a set of ordered pairs of numbers? How is this equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$?

"Equivalent" makes no sense in this case. One could define equivalence in many distinct ways. When you say "constructed from" I assume you are searching for a bijection.